# R lines command not adding lines in lineplot

Tags: r

When trying to run my code on R, it runs and produces half the job. The lines command does not add the desired second line and I do not understand why. Thank you for the help! 
Code:

```
Forceps <- c(6.61, 4.87, 3.23, 2.00, 1.29, 0.98)
Vacuum <- c(5.05, 7.21, 7.66, 5.93, 5.45, 4.40)
year <- c(1990, 1994, 1998, 2002, 2006, 2010)
plot(year, Forceps, type = "l", xlab = "Year", ylab = "Frequency", main = "Forceps (black) vs Vacuum (red) ", ylim = c(0,10))
lines(year, Vacuum, col = "red”)
```

Comment: wrong quote in lines for the color

Comment: You've got to be kidding me. I am actually in awe that that was the problem.Thank you for the help man.